# How to get laravel eloquent data toArray with pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my code.

```
$orders = Order::with('customer')->withCount('orderItems')->paginate(50)->toArray();
```

This code return me the blank page. No data return. So here's what I did wrong?

Comment: Why do you need toArray()? This strips the paginator information

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Laravel pagination, it simply gives you an array of Data.
You don't need to convert to `toArray()`.Use the following code :

```
$orders = Order::with('customer')->withCount('orderItems')->paginate(15);
```

The response of the pagination will be the following :

```
        Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "meta": {
    "page": {
      "current-page": 2,
      "per-page": 15,
      "from": 16,
      "to": 30,
      "total": 50,
      "last-page": 4
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=1&page[size]=15",
    "prev": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=1&page[size]=15",
    "next": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=3&page[size]=15",
    "last": "http://localhost/api/v1/posts?page[number]=4&page[size]=15"
  },
  "data": [...]
}
```